# Rails create action undefined method 'each' for nil:NilClass

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

In my Rails app I'm creating a form with contentEditable div's, so I have to manually send all the data through an AJAX "PUT" request to my controller. However, the create action is no longer working, and throwing this error:

```
Started POST "/submissions" for 98.245.21.165 at 2013-09-25 20:57:51 +0000                                                                                                
Processing by SubmissionsController#create as JSON                                                                                                                        
Parameters: {"title"=>"fyc", "content"=>"fuc", "folder_id"=>"1"}                                                                                                        
User Load (80.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1                                                                                        
(81.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "submissions" WHERE "submissions"."title" = 'fyc'                                                                                       
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 181ms                                                                                                                              

NoMethodError (undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass):                                                                                                                 
  app/controllers/submissions_controller.rb:16:in `create'
```

Here's my create action in the submissions controller:

```
def create 

    ajax_title = params[:title]
    ajax_content = params[:content]
    ajax_folder = params[:folder_id]
    ajax_parent = params[:parent_id]
    ajax_children = params[:children]

    @submissions = Submission.where(title: ajax_title)

    if @submissions.empty?
    @submission = Submission.create({title: ajax_title, content: ajax_content, user_id: current_user.id, folder_id: ajax_folder, parent_id: ajax_parent, children: ajax_children})
    else
        @submissions[0].content = ajax_content
        @submissions[0].save
    end
end
```

Line #16, where Rails is throwing the NoMethodError, is the line after `if @submissions.empty?` where the Submission instance is created.

My only thought is that maybe at the top where I'm putting the params into ajax_ variables, it's returning nil? I raked my routes and can see that I do have a `/submissions` PUT request that routes to this create action, so that's not the problem.

Here's the AJAX call in question:

```
$("#save-entry").click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/submissions",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {title: $("#title-create-partial").text(), content: $("#content-create-partial").text(), folder_id: <%= @folder.id %>},
                complete: function(){
                    $.get("/ajax_load_events/", {folder: <%= @folder.id %>}, null, "script");
                }
            });
        });
```

Like I said, I'm using HTML5 contentEditable divs for the form inputs, so I can't really rely on Rails to do the AJAX call for me, as far as I know. This error only started occurring recently, and I'm not sure how it started.

Any ideas? I'm desperate at this point.

**Update** Here's my Submission.rb model:

```
class Submission < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :user
belongs_to :folder
belongs_to :parent, :class_name => 'Submission'
has_many :children, :class_name => 'Submission', :foreign_key => 'parent_id', :order => ('updated_at DESC')

attr_accessible :content, :title, :user_id, :folder_id, :parent_id, :children

def self.search(search)
  if search
      where('name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%")
  else
      scoped
  end
end

def attributes_with_children
  attributes.merge(children: children.map(&:attributes_with_children))
end

end
```

And my Folder.rb model:

```
class Folder < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :title, :user_id, :parent_id

belongs_to :user
belongs_to :parent, :class_name => 'Folder'
has_many :children, :class_name => 'Folder', :foreign_key => 'parent_id'
has_many :submissions, :order => ('updated_at DESC')

def self.search(search)
where("title like ?", "%#{search}%")
end

end
```

Comment: Can you remove `parent_id` and `children` keys from the line 16 create hash one by one and see if it works..

Comment: Okay, I'll do that now

Comment: Oh hey, that worked after removing the children key. I do need the children key when a Submission instance is the child of another, though. Any idea why it's doing that?

Comment: first can you update the post with more info on how submission, parent and children are related

Comment: Added my submission.rb and folder.rb models. Maybe looking at those will help. Basically submission's are supposed to be able to have nested-submissions, or children. From a higher-level all submission's belong to a Folder.

Comment: You realize your ajax function doesn't contain the params for :parent_id or :children, right?

Comment: added an answer...you can run `rails console` and verify it with some dummy values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `submission has_many children` then

`Submission.create(:children => nil)` would throw the following error as it expects an array for `children`

```
NoMethodError: You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.each
```

However `Submission.create(:children => [])` would not throw errors.

In your example `params[:children]` was `nil` and thus it throws the error. So in the controller you can do

```
ajax_children = Array(params[:children])
#=> [] if params[:children] is nil
```

This would convert `nil` to `[]` and if the param is `[1,2,3]` it remains the same.

In general,  make sure that the values passed to the model methods are in the right format in controller as user inputs can vary a lot.